# Parse json array to QMatrix4x4

Tags: json, qt

I have such an array as json-object:

```
{
"id":"1",
 "Matrix":
 [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [9,10,11,12],
    [13,14,15,16]
 ]
}
```

With `QJsonDocument`, `QJsonObject` I can already parse the array, but how can I convert it to the `QMatrix4x4`?

The content of array looks like:

```
QJsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Matrix"].toArray();

Matrix:  QJsonArray([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
```

Answer (score 1):

`QMatrix4x4` has two suitable constructors:

- [`QMatrix4x4(const float *values)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix4x4.html#QMatrix4x4-2):

  To use this constructor, you need to convert your `QJsonArray` to a data structure that provides a C-compatible floats array:

  ```
  auto jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonData);
  QJsonArray jsonArr = jsonDoc.object()["Matrix"].toArray();
  std::array<float, 16> myArr;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    myArr[i] =
        static_cast<float>(jsonArr.at(i / 4).toArray().at(i % 4).toDouble());

  QMatrix4x4 mat(myArr.data());
  ```
- [`QMatrix4x4(float m11, float m12, ...)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix4x4.html#QMatrix4x4-3):

  To use this constructor, you need to pass elements from your `QJsonArray` as separate arguments to the constructor. You can do that manually, or you can  leverage some template meta-programming tricks to make the compiler generate that for you:

  ```
  template <std::size_t... indexes>
  QMatrix4x4 jsonArrayToQMatrix4x4Impl(const QJsonArray &jsonArray,
                                       std::index_sequence<indexes...>) {
    return QMatrix4x4(static_cast<float>(
        jsonArray.at(indexes / 4).toArray().at(indexes % 4).toDouble())...);
  }

  QMatrix4x4 jsonArrayToQMatrix4x4(const QJsonArray &jsonArray) {
    return jsonArrayToQMatrix4x4Impl(jsonArray, std::make_index_sequence<16>{});
  }

  //usage:
  QJsonArray jsonArr = jsonDoc.object()["Matrix"].toArray();
  QMatrix4x4 mat = jsonArrayToQMatrix4x4(jsonArr);
  ```

---

If you are dealing with different `QMatrix` sizes, you might want to use this generic adapter:

```
template <typename QMatrixType, std::size_t cols, std::size_t... indexes>
QMatrixType jsonArrayToQMatrixImpl(const QJsonArray &jsonArray,
                                   std::index_sequence<indexes...> seq) {
  const std::array<float, seq.size()> array{static_cast<float>(
      jsonArray.at(indexes / cols).toArray().at(indexes % cols).toDouble())...};
  return QMatrixType(array.data());
}

template <std::size_t cols, std::size_t rows,
          typename QMatrixType = QGenericMatrix<cols, rows, float>>
QMatrixType jsonArrayToQMatrix(const QJsonArray &jsonArray) {
  return jsonArrayToQMatrixImpl<QMatrixType, cols>(
      jsonArray, std::make_index_sequence<rows * cols>{});
}

//usage:
QJsonArray jsonArr = jsonDoc.object()["Matrix"].toArray();
QMatrix4x4 mat = jsonArrayToQMatrix<4, 4, QMatrix4x4>(jsonArr);
QMatrix4x3 mat2 = jsonArrayToQMatrix<4, 3>(jsonArr);
```

---

Please note that the above examples do not check that the input `QJsonArray` is of a valid size before the conversion. When the `QJsonArray` has less than the required number of elements, the result `QMatrix` will have 0s where the missing elements should be.